# Objective C shapes and points

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to detect if a rectangle or a circle contains a point. It is not so hard, but I want to know that is there any built-in method in objective c for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rectangles (as `NSRect`s) there is the Foundation function [`NSPointInRect()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSPointInRect):

```
NSPoint somePoint = //The point you want to test for
NSRect someRect = //The rectangle you want to test in

BOOL rectContainsPoint = NSPointInRect(somePoint, someRect);
```

For circles, you can use the `NSBezierPath` instance method [`containsPoint:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/containsPoint:)

```
NSBezierPath *circlePath = //Assume this is instantiated to a circle path
NSPoint somePoint = //The point you want to test for

BOOL circleContainsPoint = [circlePath containsPoint:somePoint];
```

Equally if you have a rectangular path you could use `containsPoint:` to test whether the point is in that rectangle.

**Edit:** As NSResponder pointed out, creating a full path object may not always be the most efficient method – if you already have circle paths for some kind of drawing or something then yes, but there are probably other more efficient ways of doing it. However using paths is a built-in method of doing it.

Comment: I wouldn't create a path to test for a point in a circle.  You can just check the distance from the point to the center.

Comment: Yeah in terms of efficiency, unless you are already working with an `NSBezierPath` object you're probably right, although `Tojas` was asking for built-in methods. Fixed the answer anyway.